# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{c} \int_{x}^{c} e^{x^2+y^2}dydx$. Given $\int_{0}^{c}e^{s^2}ds = 3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, iterated-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{c} \int_{x}^{c} e^{x^2+y^2}dydx$$
Given $$\int_{0}^{c}e^{s^2}ds = 3$$
where c is a positive constant.

The solution to this question mentioned that:
$$\int_{0}^{c} \int_{x}^{c} e^{x^2+y^2}dydx = \frac{1}{2}  \int_{0}^{c} \int_{0}^{c} e^{x^2+y^2}dydx$$
Because the integral in the RHS is evaluated on a triangular region bounded by:
$$ y = x \,\,\,\&\,\,\, y = c$$
whereas the one on the LHS is a square region whose area is double the triangular region.

Though I can observe that the region on XY - plane is indeed double, I'm not sure if the relationship would hold while taking a double integral over a non-constant function.

Comment: The integrand is invariant under reflection in the line $x=y$. Since the rectangle is formed by reflecting the triangle across this line, the integral over the rectangle is indeed double that of the triangle.

Comment: @raj How can check the symmetry of a 2D function about y = x?

Comment: Reflecting a point $(a,b)$ across the line $y=x$ gives the point $(b,a)$. Hence you just need to check that the integrand stays the same when you swap $x$ and $y$ (which is obvious in this case).

Comment: The two hints given by @raj are enough to get the answer $4.5$ here !

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2} \int _0^c\int _0^c e^{x^2+y^2} dydx=\frac{\pi}{8}\text{erfi}(c)^2$$